# Why does my javascript function only work if I manually type in the inputs?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that works perfectly when the values are set manually

```
function doSomeMath(array,number){
  some math here.....
}
```

It only works when I set the monthly bill manually

```
function customer(){
 this.monthlyBill = 300;
}
```

When I do this it works fine:

```
var someArray = [.2,.3,.6];
var customerData = new customer();
doSomeMath(someArray,customerData.monthlyBill);
```

The problem is that I don't want to set it manually, I want to get the value from a form input element.

When I do this it messes up:

```
function customer(){
 this.monthlyBill = $('#monthly_bill').val(); 
}
```

I go to the #monthly_bill form and type in 300 and I get a completely different value.

What is the difference between me typing

```
this.monthlyBill = 300
```

and

```
this.monthlyBill = $('#monthl_bill').val();    // and then typing 300 into a form.
```

Comment: 300 is a number - xxx.val() is a string - try `parseInt( $('#monthl_bill').val(),10);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case

```
this.monthlyBill = $('#monthl_bill').val();
```

it is considered a string. You need to parse it to an integer

So basically:

```
this.monthlyBill = parseInt($('#monthl_bill').val());
```

Comment: @JamesAllardice only needed if different than 10

Comment: @Topener - If the input had a trailing `0` it would be assumed to be an octal number. `parseInt("010")` returns `8`. `parseInt("010", 10)` returns `10`. It's safer to always include the radix.

Comment: No, only needed if a leading 0 was present - 08 or 09 fails otherwise as illegal octal

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment and a demo

300 is a number - xxx.val() is a string - try parseInt( $('#monthl_bill').val(),10);

,10 radix is needed in case someone enters leading 0s since that denotes octal

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/f3wyW/)